# Ctypes “expected LP_c_double instance instead of tuple”

Tags: python, ctypes

I have a C extension I want to call from Python.  The C extension takes a pointer to an array of pointers and three pointers to arrays of int64_t values.  I have called this C extension using a wrapper written in C and here is how I do it in C (in relevant part):

```
int64_t ptr_array_out[3];
int64_t *ptr_array_ptr = ptr_array_out;
ptr_array_out[0] = (int64_t)file_ptr1;
ptr_array_out[1] = (int64_t)file_ptr2;

int64_t type_array_out[3];
int64_t *ptr_type_array_ptr = type_array_out;
type_array_out[0] = 4; // double_precision
type_array_out[1] = 4; // double_precision

int64_t length_array_out[3];
int64_t *length_array_ptr = length_array_out;
length_array_out[0] = file_info[0];
length_array_out[1] = file_info[1];

int64_t s_data_out[3];
int64_t *s_array_ptr = s_data_out;
s_data_out[0] = 300
```

Now I am replicating it in ctypes.  The only difference is that the first array (ptr_array_ptr) passes an array of pointers to arrays in memory instead of file pointers.  Here is what I have done so far:

```
ptr_array_ptr = (ctypes.c_double * len(q))(*q), (ctypes.c_double * len(z))(*z)
ptr_type_array_ptr = (ctypes.c_longlong(4)),(ctypes.c_longlong(4))
length_array_ptr = (ctypes.c_longlong(len(q))), (ctypes.c_longlong(len(z)))
s_array_ptr = (ctypes.c_longlong(maxval1)), (ctypes.c_longlong(maxval2))

hShObj = ctypes.CDLL("(pathto shared obj)/SharedObjName.so")
CallName = hShObj.Main_Entry_fn

CallName.argtypes = [ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double),ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_longlong),ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_longlong),ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_longlong)]

CallName.restype = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int64)

ret_ptr = CallName(ptr_array_ptr, ptr_type_array_ptr, length_array_ptr, s_array_ptr)
```

But I get this error from Python:

```
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <class 'TypeError'>: expected LP_c_double instance instead of tuple
```

I have researched this and found several answers on Stack Overflow and elsewhere in various contexts, but nothing that addresses this specific situation.  I’m not a ctypes novice but I haven’t worked with it in several years so I’m not sure how to solve this.

Thanks very much for any help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listing [[Python.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes).

You're creating tuples (due to *comma*s (***,***)) for the 4 elements. Check [[Python.Docs]: Data Structures - Tuples and Sequences](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences).

A fix would be to create a *2D* array. Unfortunately, I am not aware of an elegant initialization method, so I used 2 (plain old) nested *for* loops:

> ```py
> >>> import ctypes as ct
> >>>
> >>>
> >>> q = [1, 2, 3]
> >>> z = [4, 5, 6, 7]
> >>>
> >>> ptr_array_ptr = (ct.c_double * len(q))(*q), (ct.c_double * len(z))(*z)  # @TODO - cfati: this is a tuple
> >>> ptr_array_ptr
> (<__main__.c_double_Array_3 object at 0x000001444D9A7EC0>, <__main__.c_double_Array_4 object at 0x000001444D9C2340>)
> >>> type(ptr_array_ptr)
> <class 'tuple'>
> >>> [type(e) for e in ptr_array_ptr]
> [<class '__main__.c_double_Array_3'>, <class '__main__.c_double_Array_4'>]
> >>>
> >>> ptr_array_ptr[0][0], ptr_array_ptr[1][0]
> (1.0, 4.0)
> >>>
> >>> # Start over
> >>> lists = (q, z)
> >>> max_len = max(len(e) for e in lists)
> >>> max_len
> 4
> >>> Arr = (ct.c_double * max_len) * len(lists)  # Array type
> >>> Arr
> <class '__main__.c_double_Array_4_Array_2'>
> >>>
> >>> arr = Arr()  # array
> >>> arr
> <__main__.c_double_Array_4_Array_2 object at 0x000001444D9C22C0>
> >>> arr[0][0], arr[1][0], arr[0][2], arr[1][2], arr[0][3], arr[1][3]
> (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
> >>>
> >>> for i0, l in enumerate(lists):
> ...     for i1, c in enumerate(l):
> ...         arr[i0][i1] = c
> ...
> >>>
> >>> arr[0][0], arr[1][0], arr[0][2], arr[1][2], arr[0][3], arr[1][3]
> (1.0, 4.0, 3.0, 6.0, 0.0, 7.0)
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer . Does this work to pass the pointer to my function:  ret_ptr = CallName(arr, ptr_type_array_ptr,length_array_ptr,singleton_array_ptr) -- where I substitute "arr" in the first position to call the shared object?

Comment: You're welcome! :)  You have to apply this principle to all 4 variables. I think it should work with them (worst case you'd have to cast them when passed to the function: for this one it's `ct.cast(arr, ct.POINTER(ct.c_double))`. But I can't say for sure what the behavior will be without looking at the function signature (and maybe dome documentation or a working *C* example), as the way variables and function parameters come together seems a bit strange to me. If it doesn't work as expected please submit another question.